# Get the chargin process intensity

Tags: charging

I link my Samsung Galaxy S3 to the computer's USB port using a non-original power cord. 
I've found charging process very slow, so I would test the intensity whereby power cord supply  energy to the phone.

There's an app for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use "Battery Monitor Widget" app from Play Store. It can monitor the current flowing through the battery while charging. 
I identified my Nexus 7s charger and an aftermarket charger's performance this way.